# ¿Dónde está el archivo modificable del <head> en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, https, plesk

Necesito modificar el `<head>` de una página web hecha en Wordpress.

¿Dónde está ese archivo para modificarlo a mano?

Comment: Ummm creo has editado la pregunta mientras respondía, cambiando totalmente el tema y contenido de ella. Es mejor crear otra nueva en estos casos porque sino las posibles respuestas de cada problema ya no se corresponden...

Comment: @Pavlo cuando alguien se toma el trabajo de analizar tu pregunta y responderla, conviene honrar el trabajo hecho. ¿Podrías [formular una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) sobre el problema con el HTTPS? Gracias!

Comment: Considerando que tu pregunta iba por el lado de habilitar el https (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119038/problema-https-wordpress-plesk) creo que es mejor dar esta por respondida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

1. Editando el archivo **header.php** de la plantilla, que está ubicado en:

   `/wordpress/wp-contents/themes/tuplantillaactiva/header.php`
2. Desde el panel de control de wordpress:

   - Ir a "Diseño – Editor de temas"
   - Seleccionar el tema en uso
   - Seleccionar la cabecera (header.php)
   - Editar el código según necesites

   *Nota: Requiere que la carpeta tenga permisos de escritura.*
3. Usando un plugin específico para esa labor (recomendado: [*Insert Headers and Footers*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/))

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres agregar algún `<script>` o `<style>` en la etiqueta `<head>` del sitio puedes utilizar el hook 'wp_head' para mas información, visita la documentación de WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/

Ejemplo para insertar estilos en la etiqueta `<head>`

```
function hook_css() {
    ?>
        <style>
            .wp_head_example {
                background-color : #f1f1f1;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_css');
```

Ejemplo para insertar scripts en la etiqueta `<head>`

```
function hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('Page is loading...');
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_javascript');
```