# Problema HTTPS wordpress, plesk

Tags: wordpress, https, plesk

Buenas, tengo una web hecha en wordpress.

Al ponerla en HTTPS no me carga los estilos y da algunos problemas. El error que me da es este

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.miweb.es/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.miweb.es/wp-content/themes/miweb-child/style.css?ver=3.0.60'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

en realidad da más de uno.

He probado de acceder al header de la página pero lo que me encuentro ahí no tiene ningún link directo a los estilos, tiene código propio de wordpress.

Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: instalaste tu wordpress sin https y ahora estás tratando de implementarlo, o siempre fue https?

Comment: Hola de nievo, ¿te valió borrar todo el cache? Edita la pregunta con las nuevas modificaciones para que las tengamos en cuenta

Comment: Si, el wordpress se instaló en http y se cambió posteriormente e https, y lo de la cache no funcionó

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la URL de la página? ¿Has forzado el https en `Plesk`? Actualiza la pregunta con lo que se ha intentado para tenerlo en un único sitio. Ademas por favor, agrega la versión de PHP, Wordpress y plugins que tengas. A ver si con eso sacamos algo más en claro.

Comment: Hola @PavloB. te ¿Valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `Wordpress` guarda todas las `URL` de los `post` y los `attachments` con la URl completa en la `BBDD`, por lo que aunque lo fuerces desde Plesk, `Wordpress` siempre intetará *pintar* lo que tiene en la `BBDD`.

Te recomiendo usar alguna herramienta de `replace` de manera que reemplaces todo: `http://midominio.com` por `https://midominio.com` en toda la `BBDD`.

Yo te recomiendo la siguiente, si la descomprimes en la raíz de `Wordpress` él mismo te coge los datos de la `BBDD`: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

De esa manera cambiaras todas las referencias de `http` de tu dominio a `https` y así `Wordpress` ya estará preparado para *pintar* esas `URL` correctamente y no tendras contenido mixto, salvo que en el tema o en algún plugin esté puesto en el propio código `a fuego`.

Si es así te tocara editar esos ficheros a mano.

Como ya he comentado debajo (comentarios) algo que se debería de hacer también es vaciar todo el cache. Tanto del navegador como de Wordpress si existiera.

Tal y como comentan también ,forzar a que Wordpress sea bajo `HTTPS` es una opción, pero no creo que sea la mejor, ya que si en la `BBDD` o en algún sitio se sigue haciendo referencia a `http` vas a seguir teniendo `contenido mixto`, o pero, un error de carga de algún recurso.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, y luego te cuento, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: y a la duda haz un respaldo de base de datos

Comment: Si, eso siempre. Cada vez que se tenga que realizar alguna modificación en masa en alguna `BBDD`, lo mejor es hacer siempre un backup por si acaso.

Comment: Lo he probado, he sustituido todos los `http://miweb.com` por `https://miweb.com`en la base de datos, pero sigue igual. Cuando cargo la página sin poner el https carga bien, pero si carga con el https al principio, no carga los estilos.

Comment: Asegúrate de borrar todo el caché posible de la web (si tuvieras algún plugin) ademas del posible caché que tengas en tu navegador (siempre con un navegador que no uses en modo incógnito). Si aún con eso no se soluciona, busca dentro del código no sea que lo tengas puesto `a fuego`

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de tus conocimientos y tiempo que quieras dedicarle::

**Mediante plugin**

Esta opción es la más sencilla:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

**Con herramientas**

http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/

Con esta herramienta, subiremos una copia de nuestra DB y automáticamente remplazará el dominio anterior (http) por el nuevo (https)

**Mediante Functions.php**

Otra manera, es realizar alguna función en tú functions.php que remplace todos los http por https en la salida, pero básicamente será lo mismo que el plugin anterior.

**Manual**

Como último recurso, y un poco más entretenido es hacerlo todo manual:

En la config de wordpress:

Ajustes - Generales modificamos tanto la dirección de Wordpress, como la dirección del sitio.

A continuación, forzar al administrador de WP escribimos en wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Ahora toca descargar una copia del sitio web completo, donde buscaremos http:// en todo el proyecto para localizar cualquier llamada en protocolo no seguro, aquí no se trata de remplazar todo directamente, si no de analizar detalladamente cada aparición para ver si realmente hay que modificarla.

Después, actualizar los enlaces en tú DB (deberás actualizar el código SQL, con tantos formatos como necesites):

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET    post_content = ( Replace (post_content, 'src="http://', 'src="//') )
WHERE  Instr(post_content, 'jpeg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'jpg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'gif') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'png') > 0;
```

Por si tuviera comillas simples:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET   post_content = ( Replace (post_content, "src='http://", "src='//") )
WHERE  Instr(post_content, 'jpeg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'jpg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'gif') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'png') > 0;
```

En caso que uses opciones personalizadas:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value=(REPLACE (meta_value, 'src="http://','src="//'));
```

Por último, forzamos HTTPS en apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Observaciones**

Como comentas cuando accedes a la plantilla del header, no localizas ninguna carga directa de recursos, esto es por que se realiza mediante actions y hooks. Probablemente encuentres algo del estilo a: `wp_head();`, este es el action que se encarga de generar todo el contenido que se pasa mediante los archivos de funciones. Probablemente en tú functions.php o quizás esté organizado de otro modo dependiendo de la plantilla que uses, es donde encontrarás las llamadas a los recursos del sitio web, por lo que la manera de localizar los recursos exactos, se ha de hacer un seguimiento del código hasta llegar al resultado.

Saludos,